# Node (memory leak, v8 snapshot) - is it bad practice to use a connection promise?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, sequelize.js, bluebird

I didn't want DB requests to run accidentally before connection, so the connect method returns a promise and every single DB method uses `connectPromise.then()`.

It seems like my app is leaking memory, so I'm wondering if that could be the cause. The top offender in the v8 heap memory snapshot is titled `sql` and contains a lot of stuff from bluebird promises and domains. I don't really know what to make of it, but that one single connect promise came to mind.

[image]

EDIT: I have confirmed that the source of the problem is indeed my practice of keeping around a promise from sequelize. For the sake of testing, I tried refreshing that promise every 30 seconds and my application stopped gathering more and more memory.

I have opened a [issue in sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2513)

Comment: Bluebird promises are _tiny_ in size compared to other promises (and compared to native promises too). That said a leak is always possible and no code is bug safe. Is it possible you're keeping references to all the promises you create?

Comment: In the very top of the v8 snapshot, there's an object called "sql", don't know how it got the name. All it has is references to errors, domains and promises.

Comment: This might sound strange - but can you update Bluebird to the most recent version and see if the problem goes away?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is it, but the v8 snapshot led me to this file, it mentions events and promises and stores things internally on a promise under a key 'sql' - [sequelize promise code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/66c45e013748e089dc6ef325c154c9697a4ff75c/lib/promise.js)

Comment: Ok, so every single memory retaining branch has this sequence in it: `Array > 'sql' > _events > connectPromise`

Comment: Sequelize has `.sql` events added to its promises - maybe you're keeping a reference to those handlers from outside which would prevent the promise itself from being collected.

Comment: Well, the code comments say that it's somehow designed to chain sql stuff between chained promises. That leads me to believe that my strategy of using one long-lived "connect promise" is wrong. I want to make it clear - I do store exactly one promise in the global space.

Comment: You might want to open a GitHub issue, if your strategy doesn't work they might want to rethink some stuff - it sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: I [have](https://github.com/sequelize/doc/issues/171), thanks

Comment: Sequelize dev here, there's definitely a leak in sequelize coming from the fact that we wanted to maintain BC for sql events when we moved to promises primarily.

We'll be working on a possible solution in the GH issue, it should definitely be possible to deal with long lived resolved promises.

Comment: @MickHansen - thanks a lot for the confirmation

Comment: 2.4.3 bluebird fixed a memory leak related to `receiver0` references, you could try that too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are writing a server, why not make DB connections before listening on a port?

```
db.connect().then(function(){
     server.listen(function(){

     });
});
```

I am not saying the issue with Sequelize is not real, but I think it would be a good idea not call `connect().then()` every time you make a db request.

There are places for this type of pattern and this is not one of them, I think.

It looks like Bluebird is not working well with [domains](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html), and that is where the memory leak is occurring. Bluebird is the only promise library that I know of that makes an attempt to properly propagate domains in Node.js.

Comment: The promise from the connect is kept, I'm not calling connect repeatedly.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow, if you add more code I can try

Comment: At the top, I have something like `var connectPromise = db.connect()` and then every data fetching method is using that promise, like `function find(query) { return connectPromise.then(db.find.bind(db, query)) }`. This is just an example I made up right now, not how the code looks, the problem has been resolved for a while :)

Comment: yeah ok I see np that makes sense